# Is the location of mmssms.db hidden when using a file manager?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to find the location of android telephony folder and look for the mmssms.db sqlite database and i can't seem to find anything.

I want to copy that file to my computer so that i can read it using php.Is the location of that file hidden.I have tried looking for it using Es File Explorer and i couldn't find it.

Is it possible to view the location of the sqlite database using a file explorer?.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to view the location of the sqlite database using a
>   file explorer?

I think `file manager` apps cant read `db` file, use apps like `SQLite Explorer` instead.

Comment: @NotModerator I mean something like this : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager

Comment: Installing the app that can recognize the sqlite3 and db extensions is one thing,finding the location of mmssms.db is another.

Comment: @NotModerator i remembered i can copy the `db` file, but i dont remember which apps to use @@ I think i pull it from DDMS (Eclipse)